# How do I find javascript syntax errors in my PhoneGap app?

Tags: javascript, debugging, mobile, syntax, phonegap

I have a PhoneGap app that just won't execute my javascript code.  All I know is that it's a syntax error.  `Weinre` can only tell me that it can't find the objects and/or properties I've created.

I've deployed the source code on an apache server and it loads and executes in a desktop/mobile web browser without error.  There must be a difference in javascript parsers or something.  How can I debug this?

Comment: Weinre is the only way, or simple run with browser and use inspect element, console.logs, alerts, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: I was using the newer ES6 `let` keyword to set a variable.  Whatever browser PhoneGap embeds doesn't support it yet.